# Problems appending an embed player properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with some icons, such as fire, coffee cup, car. The main idea here is that when a user clicks on these icons, I want a specific ambient sound to be played according to which icon was clicked. The problem here is that I am not able to properly embed a player into the unordered list the way I want.

For example, at the moment when clicking any icon, the traffic ambient sound is being played, even though the corresponding traffic icon was never clicked. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <h3 class="nav-title">Trancool</h3>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main-content">
        <header class="main-header">
            <h1>Trancool</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="primary-content">
            <ul class="song-list">
                <li class="play icons"><i class="coffee fa fa-coffee fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="play icons"><i class="traffic fa fa-car fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="play icons"><i class="rain fa fa-tint fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="play icons"><i class=" fire fa fa-fire fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div>
    <footer class="main-footer">
    <footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/trancool.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>









$('.song-list').on('click', 'i', function(event){
    if($(event.target.className === 'coffee')){
        if($('embed').length === 0){
            $(this).append('<embed id="embed_player" src="audio/cafe.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>')
        }
        else{
            $('embed').remove();
        }
    }

    if($(event.target.className === 'rain')){
        if($('embed').length === 0){
            $(this).append('<embed id="embed_player" src="audio/rain.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>')
        }
        else{
            $('embed').remove();
        }
    }

    if($(event.target.className === 'traffic')){
        if($('embed').length === 0){
            $(this).append('<embed id="embed_player" src="audio/traffic.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>')
        }
        else{
            $('embed').remove();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `audio()` api to play these files on click. Here's an example.

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
    var file = this.getAttribute('data-file'),
        audio = new Audio('http://skwaat.com/clips/'+file);
    audio.play();
  });
}
```

```html
<li data-file="theyoutubes.mp3">file1</li>
<li data-file="iloveyou.mp3">file2</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Now the problem is trying to stop the audio by clicking on the same icon if the audio is playing. I am having difficulties with this...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the embed from your js code and put one time on your html, change the icon class to id and then try this

```js
var sounds = {
  'coffee': 'audio/cafe.wav',
  'rain': 'audio/rain.mp3',
  'traffic': 'audio/traffic.mp3'
};

$('.song-list').on('click', 'i', function(event) {
    var file = sounds[event.target.id];
    $('#embed_player').attr('src', file);
});
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <h3 class="nav-title">Trancool</h3>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main-content">
        <header class="main-header">
            <h1>Trancool</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="primary-content">
            <ul class="song-list">
                <li class="play icons"><i id="coffee" class="fa fa-coffee fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="play icons"><i id="traffic" class="fa fa-car fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="play icons"><i id="rain" class=" fa fa-tint fa-trancool-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </ul>
            <embed id="embed_player" src=""  autostart="true" >
        </div>
    <div>
    <footer class="main-footer">
    <footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```